# IdentityServer4 + Blazor

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, blazor

I'm trying to build a small micro-service architecture with:
- an IdentityServer 4 service
- an applicative API service
- a web app, as another service

My client code is mainly inspired from @McGuireV10 code here:
https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/15/blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect.html

The problem is that I got an issue and can't find a way to fix it :

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The payload was invalid.'
```

with this stack trace :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(byte* pbCiphertext, uint cbCiphertext, byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, uint cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(System.ArraySegment<byte> ciphertext, System.ArraySegment<byte> additionalAuthenticatedData) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(byte[] protectedData, bool allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, out Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectStatus status)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(byte[] protectedData, bool ignoreRevocationErrors, out bool requiresMigration, out bool wasRevoked)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket>.Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.ReadCookieTicket()  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions>.AuthenticateAsync()  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, string scheme)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.AuthenticateAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, string scheme)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.SetRoutingAndContinue(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.dll!Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Tracing.AbpCorrelationIdMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate next)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.UseMiddlewareInterface.AnonymousMethod__1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context context)   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.ProcessRequestAsync()   Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.HandleRequest() Unknown
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Execute()   Unknown
```

Here is an overview of the application services.

[image]

So, on one side I have started the identity server, with this startup code:

```
    context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["App:SelfUrl"];//configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                    options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("role");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("phone");
                    options.Scope.Add("ProductFly");

                    options.ClaimActions.MapAbpClaimTypes();

                    options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        // called if user clicks Cancel during login
                        OnAccessDenied = context =>
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/");
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Then, the web app startup code:

```
            context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                    options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("role");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("phone");
                    options.Scope.Add("ProductFly");

                    options.ClaimActions.MapAbpClaimTypes();

                    options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        // called if user clicks Cancel during login
                        OnAccessDenied = context =>
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/");
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Also, noticed that I have my own login page, and I use this to persist my principal:

> SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new
>   ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

Here is the IdentityServer setup code:

private static void AddIdentityServer(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var configuration = services.GetConfiguration();
        var builderOptions = services.ExecutePreConfiguredActions();

```
    var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    });

    if (builderOptions.AddDeveloperSigningCredential)
    {
        identityServerBuilder = identityServerBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    identityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryClients(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"));

    services.ExecutePreConfiguredActions(identityServerBuilder);

    if (!services.IsAdded<IPersistedGrantService>())
    {
        identityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryPersistedGrants();
    }

    if (!services.IsAdded<IClientStore>())
    {
        identityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryClients(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"));
    }

    if (!services.IsAdded<IResourceStore>())
    {
        identityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryApiResources(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:ApiResources"));
        identityServerBuilder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:IdentityResources"));
    }
}
```

And it use the following record to setup:

> "GrantType":"client_credentials" "ClientId":"Product_App"
>   "ClientName":"Product_App" "Description":"Product_App"
>   "ClientUri":null, "LogoUri":null, "Enabled":true,
>   "ProtocolType":"oidc", "RequireClientSecret":true,
>   "RequireConsent":false, "AllowRememberConsent":true,
>   "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken":true, "RequirePkce":false,
>   "AllowPlainTextPkce":false, "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser":false,
>   "FrontChannelLogoutUri":null,
>   "FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired":true, "BackChannelLogoutUri":null,
>   "BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired":true, "AllowOfflineAccess":true,
>   "IdentityTokenLifetime":{"$numberInt":"300"},
>   "AccessTokenLifetime":{"$numberInt":"31536000"},
>   "AuthorizationCodeLifetime":{"$numberInt":"300"},
>   "ConsentLifetime":null,
>   "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime":{"$numberInt":"31536000"},
>   "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime":{"$numberInt":"1296000"},
>   "RefreshTokenUsage":{"$numberInt":"1"},
>   "UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh":false,
>   "RefreshTokenExpiration":{"$numberInt":"1"},
>   "AccessTokenType":{"$numberInt":"0"}, "EnableLocalLogin":true,
>   "IncludeJwtId":false, "AlwaysSendClientClaims":false,
>   "ClientClaimsPrefix":"client_", "PairWiseSubjectSalt":null,
>   "UserSsoLifetime":null, "UserCodeType":null,
>   "DeviceCodeLifetime":{"$numberInt":"300"},

Does someone has an idea to solve this ? Or at least to debug it ?

PS: I'm searching since a few days without success !

Comment: Your IS4 startup is not good, this the startup for an hybrid flow service use the quickstart in memory template to begin : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. Hybrid ? I use OIDC between my services and Cookies between my 2 web apps (The identity-login one and the web application). What is wrong ? (and why please ?). PS: The sample use Google, I use my ownl Login/Password page ! Thanks

Comment: You are using a startup code for an MVC application in your IS4 server

Comment: The sample doesn't use Google, it's the setup for an external Idp you can use or not.

Comment: You should start by reading the [IS4 doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks, but my custom login page is a MVC page ! So, yes it is MVC !

Comment: I am talking about your IS4 setup, not your web app startup

Comment: Mee too... My IdentityServer has custom login page by example, my login page on the identity server use MVC ;-)

Comment: Ok, but where do you setup IS4 services and OIDC enpoints ? You post the same code twice.

Comment: @aguafrommars I have updated the question with more details. In the last section there is the code and the OIDC setup that come from the database.

Comment: Do you use blazor wasm or blazor server ?

Comment: You try to use the client credential flow, your Product_App client's grant type is client_credentials. But that can't work. For an MVC app you should use the hybrid grant type, if you want to sign in a user.  The client_credentials grant type is used to authenticate the app with out user. It's a machine-to-machine flow : [Client Credentials Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials)

Comment: If your app is a blazor wasm app then use the authorization_code grant type with PKCE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206027/discussion-between-clubberlang-and-agua-from-mars).